# What does this TSAN exception indicate?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-concurrency, macos-ventura

When I run my code with TSAN enabled I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception thrown.

I am seeing the following error in debug navigator:

`#0 0x0000000104becb44 in __tsan::ThreadClock::release(__tsan::DenseSlabAllocCache*, __tsan::SyncClock*) ()`

The stack trace is not in my code.

Without TSAN I am seeing the following in the console:

`(Fig) signalled err=-16993`

Anybody seen this before?

This is under the new Beta 6 Xcode running under Ventura 13.0 Beta (22A5331f), on an M1 Mac.

Comment: You are far more likely to get help if you provide a [code example that manifests this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe you’ll find someone who stumbled across this specific error message before, but if not, you’ll want to provide that example so we can help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Rob sadly it’s a large code base and was working before trying Ventura. But I’m going to try and isolate it. Yes my code is async-await but with an DispatchQueue.concurent call or two. Let me try and get it isolated…

Comment: I tried on Xcode Beta 6 on Monterey and I was unable to reproduce my problem w TSAN and async/await the I had w earlier Xcode versions (pre 13.4.1). I don't have the Ventura beta, so I cannot speak to that particular combination.

Comment: Enable `Strict Swift Concurrency` in Build Settings to `complete`. Default is `minimal`. That should catch most of the issues like sendable warnings.

Comment: @Rob and @user1046037 I've looked closely at this. The `(Fig) signalled err=-16993` was a red herring...an issue with an Image library call that arose with latest beta. But I can't find an issue with the concurrent code - it was working with prior builds - I do think that problem might be with TSAN itself. Code appears to work with this disabled.

Comment: I'm hitting this too and suspect it might be a bug in the compiler. If you still have your project, can you try building it in Xcode 13.3 beta and seeing if it reproduces?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved with Xcode 14.1 beta.